# How to Mark Traffic using IPtables?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to mark traffic, How shall I write following `code` in terms of `IPtables?`

```
/ip firewall mangle> add chain=prerouting src-address=10.1.1.1/32 action=mark-connection \
new-connection-mark=server_con

/ip firewall mangle> add chain=forward connection-mark=server_con action=mark-packet  \
new-packet-mark=server


/ip firewall mangle> add chain=prerouting src-address=10.1.1.2 
action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=workstation_con
/ip firewall mangle> add chain=prerouting src-address=10.1.1.3 
action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=workstation_con
/ip firewall mangle> add chain=prerouting src-address=10.1.1.4 
action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=workstation_con

/ip firewall mangle> add chain='''forward''' connection-mark=workstation_con  action=mark-packet \
new-packet-mark=workstations
```

*The above `code` was on `mikrotik firewall` and I want to implement them on `LinuxBox`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate MikroTik firewall rules to Linux iptables rules pretty easily.  The only real difference is that iptables marking isn't quite as pretty, it likes 32 bit flags instead of nice long names, but "1" suffices most of the time.

According to the iptables man pages:

- `add chain=prerouting` : `-t mangle -A PREROUTING` (Appends a new rule to the end of the mangle PREROUTING chain)
- `src-address=10.1.1.1/32` : `-s 10.1.1.1/32` (Triggers on packets with a source address of 10.1.1.1/32)
- `action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=server_con` : `-j CONNMARK --set-mark 1` (marks these connections as "1")
- `connection-mark=workstation_con action=mark-packet new-packet-mark=workstations` : `-m connmark --mark 1 -j MARK --set-mark 1` (Marks all packets associated with connection "1" with packet mark "1")

You should be able to use these translations to create a set of rules to meet your needs.

Comment: `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.1.2/32 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1`

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.1.2/32 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2`


**Now how to mark these packets 3 by using following command**
 `iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark`

Comment: From reading the iptables man page, I'm pretty sure it's the `-m connmark` module you want for the final stage, not the `-m mark` module.